# dropdown select value resets after onchange

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dynamic drop-down using php/mysql. For some reason the selected value does not stay selected. The drop-down reset to the initial value. The selected value is used to populate a table on the same php page.

```html
  <form action="" method="get">
<select name="user"  onchange="this.form.submit();">
  <?php
do {  
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row["userid"]?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row["display_name"]?></option>
  <?php
} while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a logic in your code for that.
First when you get data from form, save your dropdown value in a variable.
eg. `$user = $_GET['user'];`

Now make the following changes in your code.

```
<form action="" method="get">
<select name="user"  onchange="this.form.submit();">
  <?php
do {  
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['userid']?>" <?php if($user == $row['user_id']) { echo 'selected="selected"' } ?> >
<?php echo $row["display_name"]?></option>
  <?php
} while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added "$user = $_GET['user'];" to the code. That works great, but { echo 'selected="selected"' }?> now creates the error...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in....

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add semicolon after echo statement. The code would be `{ echo 'selected="selected"'; }`